# How to disable running Alarm Reciever?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I set my alarm receiver as follow:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("alarmId", REQUEST_CODE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                    time * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Then I am canceling it from another class:

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

But it does not work. Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Intents` are not equivalent. The first one uses `REQUEST_CODE`. The second one uses `0`. You need to make these be the same.